# How to apply jQuery ajaxPrefilter method to all require.js views?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

this is my first time asking a question so be gentle. I am working with requirejs for the first time (along with Backbone and Underscore) and I am using the jQuery ajaxPrefilter method in a view to set the base url for ajax calls like so...

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
options.url = '//mysite.com' + options.url;});
```

This way I can use simple urls like "/notes" in my models/collections. Right now it seems I have to put the ajaxPrefilter call in every view. Is there somewhere I can call it once and have it apply to all views?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did the same thing as you :

```
    $.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
        options.url = App.config.getValue('api') + options.url;
    });
```

If you're using Backbone.Router, you could put it in the initialize function like i did.

```
    define([
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'backbone',
        'app',
    ],
    function($, _, Backbone, App) {

        return Backbone.Router.extend({

            routes: {
                        '' : 'index'
                    },
                    start: function() {
                       Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
                    }
                    initialize: function() {
                        $.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
                         options.url = App.config.getValue('api') + options.url;
                       });
                    }
            });
    });
```

App.config is something i added so i get the right url for each of my environment.

Comment: Thank you, that works. And I see now that it works in other locations as well. Could you provide any insight into why you chose to put it in the router initialize function?

Comment: I didn't find (yet) any good reason to have multiple router. You could put in many place depending on how your app is configured. In my case too, the initialize function wasn't the only place, i agree.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's really a good idea if you have more than one router...

In such a case we have put jquery inits in our main app, just before launching first Backbone router...

```
myApp = {
    (....)


initialize : function(){

    // jQuery.ajax()cross-domain config
    $.ajaxSetup({xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}});

    // Start routers
    DefaultRouter.initialize();
(....)
}
```